# Cassandra eats memory

Tags: memory, cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I have *Cassandra 2.1* and following properties set:

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="5G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
```

top utility shows that cassandra eats 14.6G virtual memory:

```
KiB Mem:  16433148 total, 16276592 used,   156556 free,    22920 buffers
KiB Swap: 16777212 total,        0 used, 16777212 free.  9295960 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23120 cassand+  20   0 14.653g 5.475g  29132 S 318.8 34.9  27:07.43 java
```

It also dies with various *OutOfMemoryError* exceptions when I am accessing it from Spark.

How I can prevent this "*OutOfMemoryErrors*" and reduce memory usage?

Comment: I've set MAX_HEAP_SIZE and Xmx to 600M (development purpose) but is still using 4G at startup.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra do eat to much memory but it can be controlled but tuning the GC [Garbage Collection] setting.

GC parameters are contained in the bin/cassandra.in.sh file in the JAVA_OPTS variable.

you can apply these settings in JAVA_OPTS

```
    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
  -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=1
  -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
  -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
  -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
  -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=10
```

Or instead of specifying `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` and  `HEAP_NEWSIZE` these parameter let cassandra'script specify these parameter Because it will assign best values for these parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this options tweaks GC parameters and GC operates on heap memory.

In my case I have heap limit 5G, while cassandra eats 14g of virtual memory. So I assume that this is off-heap which could not be controlled by this options.